# ValueError when calculating Loss

Tags: python, tensorflow, conv-neural-network

I got this ValueError when running my model:

```
ValueError: Can not squeeze dim[1], expected a dimension of 1, got 18000 for 'sparse_softmax_cross_entropy_loss/remove_squeezable_dimensions/Squeeze' (op: 'Squeeze') with input shapes: [?,18000].
```

The place where the error is triggered is:

```
logits = model(image, training=True)
loss = tf.losses.sparse_softmax_cross_entropy(labels=labels, logits=logits)
accuracy = tf.metrics.accuracy(
    labels=labels, predictions=tf.argmax(logits, axis=1))
```

The error comes up when the sparse_softmax_cross entropy function gets called. The dimensions of pictures I am using are (50, 120, 3). Any clue on how I can fix that?

Comment: Have you read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49083984/valueerror-can-not-squeeze-dim1-expected-a-dimension-of-1-got-3-for-sparse) similar thread ?

Comment: I did but I can't read out what the solution is finally :/ @MohanRadhakrishnan

Comment: try: cross_entropy= tf.nn.sparse_softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(labels=labels, logits=logits); loss = tf.reduce_mean(cross_entropy). Tell me if this helps.

Comment: What are the dimensions of logits and labels? The dimension of images is irrelevant here.

Comment: ok, the error I received now is: ValueError: Rank mismatch: Rank of labels (received 2) should equal rank of logits minus 1 (received 2) @Vlad

Comment: what are the dimensions of logits and labels? print(logits.get_shape().as_list()); print(labels.get_shape().as_list()). if the second throws an exception, tell me  what it says

Comment: both are (?, 18000) when I print out the get_shape() method on them @Vlad

Comment: how the labels is defined?

Comment: try: labels = tf.placeholder(tf.int64, shape=(None), name='labels')

Comment: I get [None, 18000] for both of your commands. labels are pictures of the same size as the images. but I think you mean something else?

Comment: where is `labels` variable is defined? show this line. the problem is in the shape of the `labels`

Comment: actually I see that I never define it. I just have it mentioned in the def model_fn(features, labels, mode, params) head of the function. (I am using the mnist construct for this) https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/official/mnist/mnist.py

Comment: it must be defined somewhere, otherwise you would get `NameError` exception.

Comment: Thats true. https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/official/mnist/dataset.py#L106 I get the Dataset in this way though I get it locally from the disk. There are the labels in it.

Comment: Now I get tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: You must feed a value for placeholder tensor 'labels' with dtype int32 which makes sense because I have to give this placeholder all the data.

Comment: But yeah labels is defined as a parameter of the model_fn function

Comment: the model that you took was build for mnist dataset. It won't work for other datasets without modifications. I suggest you to start by building your own neural net step by step, trying to understand each step. Start by understanding what are placeholders, Variable, Operation, Tensor, Graph, Session. The official documentation is very good.

Comment: I see. Is there really no easy way to implement the labels though, such that this works. I mean I use just pictures instead of scalars for the labels.