# How do I load my local data into my tensorflow/keras-model?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, neural-network

I'm new to tensorflow and keras and don't know how to load my data for the model to fit.

I've tried using a tf.dataset that is built from a list of image paths and labels, but to no avail. I know that the model itself in the code below might not be well suited for my task. I just wanted to try tf out and learn how to set up a model and train it. My images have multiple formats (tiff, png, jpg) and have different sizes. That's why I need to resize them and convert them to numpy-arrays. I tried it according to this thread : [TensorFlow: training on my own image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37340129/tensorflow-training-on-my-own-image)

```
import tensorflow as tf
import random
import numpy
import cv2
from PIL import Image
from pathlib import Path
import os
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator

training_data_path = Path("/home/xxxx/validation_data")

validation_data_path = Path("/home/xxxx/validation_data")
test_data_paths = Path("/home/xxxx/test_data")
validation_image_paths = list(validation_data_path.glob("**/*"))
label_array = ["DIS","ANG", "FEA", "SAD", "SUR", "JOY", "NEU"]
label_to_index = dict((name, index) for index,name in      enumerate(label_array))

def getLabelDict(image_paths):

    all_image_labels = [label_to_index[Path(path).absolute().name[0:3]]
                    for path in image_paths]
    return all_image_labels

def getLabelList(image_paths):
    all_img_labels = list()
    for path in image_paths:
        all_img_labels.append(Path(path).absolute().name[0:3])
    return all_img_labels


def preProcessPath(path):
   return path.absolute().name


def get_ds(data_path):
    image_paths = list(data_path.glob("**/*"))
    img_paths = tf.constant(image_paths)

    dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((img_paths,     getLabelList(image_paths)))
    for path in image_paths:
        dataset.map(getPic(path))

    return dataset

def getPic(path):
    image = Image.open(path).convert('RGB')
    image = image.resize((256,256,3))
    array = numpy.array(image.getdata())
    array = array.reshape((256,256,3))
    return array


os.environ['CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES'] = '-1'


ds_inputs, ds_labels =  get_ds(test_data_paths).make_one_shot_iterator()
val_inputs, val_labels=  validation_data=get_ds(validation_data_path).make_one_shot_iterator()

model = tf.keras.Sequential([
    tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(256,256,3)),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(128, activation=tf.nn.relu),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(10, activation=tf.nn.softmax)
])

model.compile(optimizer='adam',
              loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy',
              metrics=['accuracy'])

model.fit(ds_inputs, epochs=1,  steps_per_epoch=3,validation_data=val_inputs)
```

Edit: removed unnecessary lines in the code

Right now I'm getting a type-error: TypeError: Failed to convert object of type  to Tensor. Contents:

Comment: Could you please fix your code indentation? The line below `for path in training_data_path.glob("**/*"):` should be indented. Also, you might consider having all your function definitions before your main code to make it more readable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Issues in your code:**

1. PIL resize : Takes size as a 2-tuple(width, height). You passed in 3 values.
2. get_ds: Label should be encoded as number not a string
3. Model Architecture: Since you are using 3 channel images as inputs to a Neural Network, you have to flatten them first.

### Working Code --- (explained in comments)

```
label_array = ["DIS","ANG", "FEA", "SAD", "SUR", "JOY", "NEU"]
label_to_index = dict((name, index) for index,name in enumerate(label_array))
  
# Takes as input path to image file and returns 
# resized 3 channel RGB image of as numpy array of size (256, 256, 3)
def getPic(img_path):
    return np.array(Image.open(img_path).convert('RGB').resize((256,256),Image.ANTIALIAS))

# returns the Label of the image based on its first 3 characters
def get_label(img_path):
    return Path(img_path).absolute().name[0:3]

# Return the images and corresponding labels as numpy arrays
def get_ds(data_path):
    img_paths = list()
    # Recursively find all the image files from the path data_path
    for img_path in glob.glob(data_path+"/**/*"):
        img_paths.append(img_path)
    images = np.zeros((len(img_paths),256,256,3))
    labels = np.zeros(len(img_paths))
      
    # Read and resize the images
    # Get the encoded labels
    for i, img_path in enumerate(img_paths):
        images[i] = getPic(img_path)
        labels[i] = label_to_index[get_label(img_path)]
        
    return images,labels

# Model Architecture
model = tf.keras.Sequential([
    tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(256,256,3)),
    tf.keras.layers.Flatten(),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(128, activation=tf.nn.relu),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(10, activation=tf.nn.softmax)
])

model.compile(optimizer='adam',
              loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy',
              metrics=['accuracy'])

# Load the train and validation data
train_X, train_y = get_ds("./images/")
val_X, val_y = get_ds("./v_images/")

# Finally train it
model.fit(train_X,train_y, validation_data=(val_X,val_y))

# Predictions 
model.predict(val_X)
```

Comment: i've tried your implementation. it works and trains ....and classifies with an accuracy of 0.085 ...but that's another story. thank you

Comment: @mrFunkus yes thats because the model in the above code is pretty bad model. You should ideally be using CNNs here.

Answer (score 0):

See "flow_from_directory" here
https://keras.io/preprocessing/image/

According to keras documentation this takes the path to a directory & generates batches of augmented data.
And any PNG, JPG, BMP, PPM or TIF images inside each of the subdirectories directory tree will be included in the generator.

Comment: i've tried this and it seems to load the data, but now i get the following error: tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: Can not squeeze dim[1], expected a dimension of 1, got 7
  [[{{node metrics/acc/Squeeze}}]]

Comment: I can't test this right now but check this answer . I hope it helpa https://stackoverflow.com/a/55419238/7645361